# The grep command's quiet flag is being ignored

Tags: bash

```
$ sudo service --status-all | grep -q oijawpawuouzmaomwaoiwadlknasdlknascsc &>/dev/null
 [ ? ]  hwclock.sh
 [ ? ]  kmod
 [ ? ]  plymouth
 [ ? ]  plymouth-log
$ sudo service --status-all
 [ + ]  apache-htcacheclean
 [ + ]  apache2
 [ - ]  apparmor
 [ + ]  awslogs
 [ - ]  console-setup.sh
 [ - ]  cron
 [ - ]  dbus
 [ ? ]  hwclock.sh
 [ + ]  irqbalance
 [ - ]  keyboard-setup.sh
 [ ? ]  kmod
 [ + ]  php7.2-fpm
 [ ? ]  plymouth
 [ ? ]  plymouth-log
 [ - ]  procps
 [ - ]  rsync
 [ - ]  rsyslog
 [ + ]  udev
 [ - ]  ufw
 [ - ]  unattended-upgrades
 [ - ]  uuidd
 [ - ]  x11-common
```

Wondering why the output from grep with the quiet flag is appearing, sending outputs to dev null is also failing.

I'm also confused as to why the gibberish is matching against anything.

Comment: it displays unknown [?] statuses on the standard error. Try `... 2>/dev/null`.

Comment: Perhaps that's the standard error stream from the other process?  You can confirm by redirecting it, e.g. `service 2>/dev/null`

Comment: That's it, thank you @TobySpeight , feel free to put that as the answer